# Aptana Studio - Run in webbrowser when pressing F12

Tags: aptana

So, I just edited the Run-Hotkey to be F12 instead of CTRL+F11. When I now press F12 the script runs, but it doesn't run in Firefox. It runs in the Aptana-Console. When I choose Firefox from the Drop Down it works with Firefox, but I want that when I press F12 to open Firefox. I hope that is clear enough what I want to do.

Comment: It looks like you have assigned two functions to F12 and need to unassign the Aptana-Console if you don't want to have to choose each time. Look through your key bindings again and see if you have used F12 twice.

Comment: I did this, and I unbind everything in conflict, but it still doesn't start in Firefox.

Comment: What type of file are you trying to run?